# Return no element from `Array.flatMap()` by if condition

Tags: javascript, flatmap

I have this code:

```js
  const myFunc = function (t) {
    return myArray.flatMap(clip =>
      (t < clip.start || t < clip.end) ? // Valid objects are returned in this *if* condition
        [
          { time: clip.start },
          { time: clip.end }
        ] : // how to return nothing in this *else* condition. Absolutely nothing?
        [
          {  },
          {  }
        ]
    )
  }
```

The above code used a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator of `condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse`.

Currently I'm returning empty objects of `{  }` in the case of `exprIfFalse`.

How can I return nothing in the case of `exprIfFalse`? I mean, I want absolutely nothing. I mean no array element.

Comment: Why are you setting the empty one with empty objects? That would be your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why cant you just return an empty array, any how `Array.flat` will remove those empty array from final code. In your case the array is not empty as `[]`, its an array with two empyty objects as `[{}, {}]` that will produce two empty objects `{}, {}` in the final output after `Array.flat`

You have to return something from `flatMap`. If you return nothing, the corresponding nodes will be added as `undefined`. That wont be removed with `Array.flat`. Best option is to return an empty array as below.

**Pseudo Code**

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const myFunc = function (t) {
  return myArray.flatMap(clip =>
    (clip % 2 === 0) ? // Valid objects are returned in this *if* condition
      [
        { value: clip },
        { value: clip }
      ] : // how to return nothing in this *else* condition. Absolutely nothing?
      []
  )
}
console.log(myFunc());
```